# Getting current user/session pageview from Google Analytics cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

Is it possible to extract the current page view count/number from the user who is visiting my site?

I use GA on my website and I would like to know the current page view count. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to get this information from the cookie because this information isn't stored in the cookie. If you visit any site that uses GA and look at the cookie you'll see it's just a random number (the `clientId`) that's used to identify new users from returning users.

You *could* display a count of pageviews on your site, but you'd have to query the [Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/) to do that, and the data wouldn't be live, so I'm not sure how valuable that would be.

If you wanted to more specifically show the pageview count for the current user, it'll be even harder. You'd have to set the `clientId` on a custom dimension and then query for pageviews by that custom dimension, but again that data wouldn't be live either.